# Pygame cam.get_raw() returns None

Tags: python, pygame

I'm fairly new to useing pygame and I'm trying to take a picture from the webcam and saving it as a png file. This is my code:

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera('Integrated Webcam',(640,480))
cam.start()
image = cam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(image, 'test.png')
print(cam.get_raw())
```

This prints out None and the png file that it creates is completely black

Comment: Is the camera connected? https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html#pygame.camera.Camera.get_raw might help if you have more troubles

Comment: The camera is connected. cam.query_image() returns true before cam.get_image() runs. After a cam.get_image or cam.get_raw runs though cam.query_image returns false. I don't know if this is where the issue is or not and if it is I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved, needed to pause for about .65 seconds to give time for the camera to power on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).